# SQL issue that I should be able to answer but I cannot

Tags: sql, select

Here's the tiny bit of data I am to query:

```
name       continent    area      population    gdp
Afghani    Asia         652230    25500100      20343000000
Albania    Europe       28748     2831741       12960000000
Algeria    Africa       2381741   37100000      188681000000
Andorra    Europe       468       78115         3712000000
Angola     Africa       1246700   20609294      100990000000
```

Given the above data, the request was to select two columns with France, Germany, Italy and their populations.

Here was my thought:

```
Select name, population
where name = 'France','Germany','Italy'
```

Where was any screw-up, if you would be so kind.

Comment: `FROM Table WHERE Name IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z')`

Answer (score 1):

The `=` operator doesn't take multiple arguments. You're looking for the `in` operator. Additionally, you're missing a `from` clause:

```
SELECT name, population
FROM   populations
WHERE  name IN ('France', 'Germany', 'Italy')
```

Comment: guh, should have known that